# Laravel 5.3 relationship returns wrong one

Tags: php, laravel, relation

```
class Company extends Model
{
 public function company_settings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('CompanySetting');
}

}

class SettingsGroup extends Model
{
public $table = 'settings_groups';

public function comapanySettings() {

    return $this->hasMany('CompanySetting');
}
}

 class CompanySetting extends Model
{
public function groups () {

    return $this->belongsToMany('SettingsGroups');

}

public function company_settings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Company');
}

}
```

I want to get the companys settings:
Company::whereHas('company_settings', function ($q) use ($company) {            $q->where('company_id',$company->id);})->get();

But it returns the company, not the settings. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!!

Edited with all the Models, 
$companies = Company::with('company_settings')->get(); also returns all the companies

Thanks!

Comment: That mean you've `Many To Many` relationship, show use more code please. at least the both Models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then to get the settings you can do:

```
$companies = Company::with('settings')->get();
```

Then access the first company's settings:

```
$companies ->first()->company_settings;
```

Since this returns a collection all of the collection methods are available to you:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections

To loop through them you could do:

```
$companies->each(function($company) {
    $company->company_settings;
    // Your logic here
});
```

Comment: Company settings has many to many relationships so i need belongsToMany

Comment: `whereHas` filters by a relationship, to get the settings for a company you would do `$companies = Company::with('company_settings')->get();` which will return a collection of companies.  You can access the settings of them by looping through or an example to get the first would be `$companies->first()->company_settings`

Answer (score 0):

You can't build relation with `settings` in this query. `whereHas()` works basically the same as has() but allows you to specify additional filters for the related model to check.

Try this:

```
  Company::with('company_settings')
        ->whereHas('company_settings', function ($q) use ($company)
        {
              $q->where('company_id',$company->id);
        })->get();
```